# Firebase Firestore cloud database

Tags: firebase-database

Подскажите как создать при помощи firebase Cloud Firestore многоуровневую структуру БД, которая будет включать ID зарегистрированных пользователей и данные, которые относятся к каждому из пользователей. 
Идея в том, что каждый пользователь может сохранить какую-либо информацию, в моем случае это фильм в виде объекта с некоторыми данными. Код ниже работает, но проблема в том, что каждый раз при добавлении нового документа в виде объекта предыдущий документ заменяется на новый, мне же нужен массив виде объектов

```
async addToFavorList({commit, getters}, payload) {    
            try {
                await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(getters.uid).set({
                    id: payload.id,
                    poster_path: payload.poster_path,
                    title: payload.title,
                    release_date: payload.release_date,
                    vote_average: payload.vote_average
                });  
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
}
```

Желаемый результат получается таким образом:

```
async addToFavorList({commit}, payload) {
            try {
                await firebase.firestore().collection('movies').add({
                    id: payload.id,
                    poster_path: payload.poster_path,
                    title: payload.title,
                    release_date: payload.release_date,
                    vote_average: payload.vote_average
                });
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }

}
```

Но проблема в том, что в последнем варианте у меня нет привязки к конкретному uid. Т.е. любой зарегистрированный пользователь получает данные, которые добавил другой пользователь с другим uid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [подколлекции](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections).

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('userId').collection('favorites').add({....})
```